# ExecCGI turned off in this directory

Tags: macos, apache, cgi

I'm trying to run a python cgi script on my Mac's web server. Everytime I visit the file @ localhost/site.py I get a 403 forbidden error.

I'm looking in my Apache's error log, and it says:

```
[Mon Jun 11 09:52:42 2012] [error] [client ::1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /Users/<username>/Sites/site.py
```

I've changed my httpd.conf file so that my document root is /Users//Sites

In my user's .conf file, I have the following:

```
<Directory "/Users/<username>/Sites/">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Why is it telling me ExecCGI is off, when I've allowed all options in my user's .conf file?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify and/or add a script alias to your httpd.conf

This is what mine looks like on windows.

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    #other comments removed
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't have mine setup to point to a specific user's file though.